# How to get flutter Application Size in programming

Tags: flutter, dart, device, capacity

I had Flutter Application A.

I'm trying to get :

- My Application size
- Device Capacity

But still not find out any component to archive that,

People who knows,

Please tell me, thanks,

Comment: check `Platform.executable`

Comment: @pskink Not found this @@

Comment: not found? what you mean?

Comment: `Platform.executable` - Not found this

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/index.html on the top right corner you have `"Search API docs"` search box, simply type `executable`